# ArcMap Append tool will not copy full contents of input feature class

Tags: arcmap, append

I have a versioned SDE geodatabase and and running a series of Appends between feature classes and a stand-alone file geodatabase with a schema that mirrors the input gdb.

I have, for example, an SDE feature class that contains 13k records.  When I append the layer to an empty feature class in the file gdb only about 11k records copy over.  I have recalculated the spatial extents on both.  I even set the environment tool in Append to be the input of both datasets.  It simply won't work and won't copy over the same specific records.  I don't have any subsets of the data pre-selected, fyi.

Can anyone suggest why append is failing to copy over the entire contents of the input layer?

Comment: I would join the 11k data to the 13k to see what did not get transfered. Maybe you can detect a pattern or reason for the failures.

Comment: I know which records aren't getting transferred.  there is no pattern.  There's nothing obvious going on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm concluding the issue is related to a bug in Arc 10.6.1.  I can't reproduce the problem in 10.5+